# Why is the mobile menu collapsing when I click the UL?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-development

I have a mobile nav menu I created with CSS and HTML that uses the checkbox trick to open and close the menu. The issue I'm having though is that when you open the menu and click anywhere within the .menu-content section (the UL) it just collapses the menu. I cannot figure out why this is happening. It should ONLY collapse the menu when you click the `.menu-icon` span.
Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/QuantumCelestial/pen/GRzrGJG

Here is my HTML & CSS:

```css
.mobile-nav {
  display: revert;
}
/* Rounded corner style for collapsed menu display */
.menu-wrap .menu-icon {
  position: fixed;
  right: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #26877f;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #26877f, 0 0 0 0 #26877f;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Hamburger menu icon (Middle Line) */
.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #69d2e7;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Create Top and Bottom Lines & move top line up */
.menu-wrap .hamburger::after,
.menu-wrap .hamburger::before {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  /* top: -10px; */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #69d2e7;
}
/* Move top line up */
.menu-wrap .hamburger::before {
  top: -10px;
}
/* Move bottom line down */
.menu-wrap .hamburger::after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
/* Remove input checkbox from display */
.menu-wrap .toggler {
  display: none;
}
/* Create expanded view/growing circle effect */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .menu-icon {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #26877f, 0 0 0 100vh #26877f;
  border-radius: 0;
  /* Change toggler box dimensions to fit the X */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
/* Reposition icon after box dimensions are resized */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .menu-icon .hamburger {
  top: 36px;
  left: 0px;
}
/* Rotate lines */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .menu-icon .hamburger {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
/* Rotate bottom line */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .menu-icon .hamburger::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 0;
}
/* Rotate top line */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .menu-icon .hamburger::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0; /* Added so one line isn't thicker than the other */
}
/* Styling for expanded menu content */
.menu-wrap .menu-content {
  font-size: 3rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 1.6;
  transition: all 15s ease-in;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(75%, -150%) scale(0);
  transform: translate(75%, -150%) scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  /* transition: all 0.4s ease; */
}
/* Show menu content when nav is expanded */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu-content {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
/* Styling for the nav links */
.menu-wrap a {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  color: #69d2e7;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="mobile-nav menu-wrap" role="navigation" aria-roledescription="click to expand menu options">
  <input class="toggler" type="checkbox"/>
  <span class="menu-icon"> <span class="hamburger"></span> </span>
  <ul class="menu-content">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</label>
```

Comment: First of all, check for errors. There is an undefined function toggleScroll.

Comment: I can not reproduce the error from your given code. Check out [How to create a MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). From the partially functioning example I'd be willing to bet that the problem is your whole ul is wrapped in the label, so click events might be bubbling up instead of registering the page change. I love some css puzzles, but unless there's no alternative, js would make this task more readable and trivial. Otherwise you might have to put some more thought into where your checkbox and labels are located. If you make a MWE I'm happy to review it <3

Comment: _"I cannot figure out why this is happening"_ - because clicking the associated `label`, will toggle the status of your checkbox. And since you nested the _full_ menu into your label - including that UL - clicking anywhere within that UL, also constitutes a click on your label element.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks CBroe for your answer!
My issue was that my entire nav was wrapped inside the label element and what I did not realize is that the label element automatically shifts the focus to the associated input when clicked. So I changed the label element to a nav element and I changed the first span for the menu icon to the label and associated it to the input. My codepen has been updated and below is my updated code.

```css
.mobile-nav {
  display: revert;
}
/* Rounded corner style for collapsed menu display */
.menu-wrap .menu-icon {
  position: fixed;
  right: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #26877f;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #26877f, 0 0 0 0 #26877f;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Hamburger menu icon (Middle Line) */
.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #69d2e7;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Create Top and Bottom Lines & move top line up */
.menu-wrap .hamburger::after,
.menu-wrap .hamburger::before {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  /* top: -10px; */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #69d2e7;
}
/* Move top line up */
.menu-wrap .hamburger::before {
  top: -10px;
}
/* Move bottom line down */
.menu-wrap .hamburger::after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
/* Remove input checkbox from display */
.menu-wrap .toggler {
  display: none;
}
/* Create expanded view/growing circle effect */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .menu-icon {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #26877f, 0 0 0 100vh #26877f;
  border-radius: 0;
  /* Change toggler box dimensions to fit the X */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
/* Reposition icon after box dimensions are resized */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .menu-icon .hamburger {
  top: 36px;
  left: 0px;
}
/* Rotate lines */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .menu-icon .hamburger {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
/* Rotate bottom line */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .menu-icon .hamburger::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 0;
}
/* Rotate top line */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .menu-icon .hamburger::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0; /* Added so one line isn't thicker than the other */
}
/* Styling for expanded menu content */
.menu-wrap .menu-content {
  font-size: 3rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 1.6;
  transition: all 15s ease-in;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(75%, -150%) scale(0);
  transform: translate(75%, -150%) scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  /* transition: all 0.4s ease; */
}
/* Show menu content when nav is expanded */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu-content {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
/* Styling for the nav links */
.menu-wrap a {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  color: #69d2e7;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="mobile-nav menu-wrap">
  <input id=“toggle” class="toggler" type="checkbox"/>
  <label for=“toggle” class="menu-icon"> <span class="hamburger"></span> </label>
  <ul class="menu-content">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```